# Intents to launch song, search for user in spotify app?

Tags: android, spotify

I'm trying to figure how apps like Shazam, for example, are able to launch spotify to play a specific song. Another question on SO suggested an intent like `String spotifyUri = "spotify:user:username"`  and then parsing that as a `Uri`, but instead of searching for a user that just launches spotify. How can I make spotify play a track?

**EDIT**

Looking at Logcat, it looks like Shazam does this:

```
Starting: Intent { act=android.media.action.MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH cmp=com.spotify.mobile.android.ui/.Launcher (has extras) } from pid 9959
```

How do I replicate this in my code?

**EDIT**

Ok, so apparently its something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.setAction(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.spotify.mobile.android.ui", "com.spotify.mobile.android.ui.Launcher"));
```

Now how do I tell it to search for a specific song?

Comment: Hi, im trying to do something similar, I tried your code but I get an error with the second line specifically at the INTENT_ACTION_MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH. I was wondering if you had the full code?

Comment: @Peter, see my code in the answer below. Also, you are probably getting the error because you are building against Android API 8 or below. The INTENT_ACTION_MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH was added as of API level 9.

Comment: Oh that must be it I am on API 8. Thanks so much i would have never thought of that. I know this is off topic but were you able to do anything else like interacting with the spotify app? I'm trying to do things like tell what song is being played from my app and I'm having a hard time. I thought maybe since you got this working you may have some idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, well apparently you need to use a stick a `SearchManager.Query` as an extra. [This post](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/09/supporting-new-music-voice-action.html) sort of points to that.

So, it's `intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, "michael jackson smooth criminal");`