# Launch Spotify Search via adb for Android

Tags: android, adb, spotify

I am hacking my nexus q and setting up some tools to allow users to run apps and one of the things I am trying to do is launch a song on spotify over adb so that way it can be run from say a script or call from a webpage etc.  I saw the post [Intents to launch song, search for user in spotify app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656720/intents-to-launch-song-search-for-user-in-spotify-app)  but I am not sure how to launch this via the command prompt.  I am currently at -

adb am start -a MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_MEDIA_PLAY_FROM_SEARCH -e SearchManager.QUERY "michael jackson smooth criminal" -n com.spotify.mobile.android.ui/.Launcher

This though isn't returning anything so I wasn't sure what else I many need to add or change from the command itself.  I know I am connected to the device properly and I see the start of the command called but after that nothing happens.  In the log it does show 'Duplicate finish request for Activity Record 'com.spotify.mobile.android.ui/.Launcher' so I am guessing it is running just not finishing etc.

Thanks all,
Joe

Comment: Are you sure you don't have a typo in that command line? I see a misplaced slash in "com.spotify.mobile.android.ui/.Launcher"

Comment: Normally when you start apps via adb you have the package name / the activity so if I want to launch spotify it is am start -n com.spotify.mobile.android.ui/.MainActivity and then it will popup properly. I'll try removing it but I don't think that is the issue.

Comment: Yeah, I just saw in the Android docs that the / is needed when using adb am command. My bad!