# Deezer Intent - Android

Tags: android, android-intent, deezer

I've already searched the web but haven't found any results. How can I make the Deezer app play a specific song using an intent at Android? (I'd like to do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656720/intents-to-launch-song-search-for-user-in-spotify-app) with Deezer too).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just start an ACTION_VIEW intent on "http://www.deezer.com/track/{id}".

```
String uri = "http://www.deezer.com/track/" + trackId;
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
```